# Keep topbar transparent on maximized windows

Tags: wingpanel, themes, settings

The auto transparent/solid topbar (wingpanel) in elementary OS Freya is awesome! But I'd like to keep it always transparent if the wallpaper allows it. Currently if the wallpaper allows topbar transparency but you maximize a windows, then topbar becomes solid (black).

Is there any way to keep it transparent even with maximized windows if wallpapers allows it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run these commands from terminal

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel auto-adjust-alpha false
```

that will do it but if you want to adjust the transparency

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel background-alpha 0.3
```

The **background-alpha** key can be any value between 0 and 1, and if you have dconf editor you can use it to adjust the keys too.

Comment: Once I have run this commands, is there a way to back to default config?

Comment: not tested but this should do it **gsettings reset org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel auto-adjust-alpha**

Answer (score 5):

The key has been changed in Newer version of Wingpanel like version 2.0.1. Use this instead

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel use-transparency true
```

If you want to reset, use

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel use-transparency
```

Comment: `No such schema “org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel”` :(

Comment: > `gsettings set io.elementary.desktop.wingpanel use-transparency true` that will not work on maximized window

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for the current gsettings command, it's

```
gsettings set io.elementary.desktop.wingpanel use-transparency true
```

On my Hera it was already set to true however, so it didn't really solve the original problem.